# UITableview Grouping

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

I have a sorted array of strings. I want to group them using tableview section according to  first letter similar to iPhone contact.

I am new to iOS can any one help me to do this, The array is retrieving from server.

and also there is a search option for table view

Comment: Using table views is covered in every tutorial on iOS basics. If you have any specific problem, please describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to group and index the items alphabetically?
There is a system class to do that, called UILocalizedIndexedCollation.

Here is a nice tutorial for it:
http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/230

Comment: The above one is also correct but it is a simple step by step tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this given below link

http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2009/12/uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-uilocalizedindexedcollation/